# SSIS - Data Flow - How do I split on a 0 row return?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to make a conditional split in the data flow in SSIS.

My Source can  return 0 rows (and is expected)

I want the split to split on if there is 0 rows returned, or any rows returned.

The problem I am seeing currently is that the Data Flow stops if there are 0 rows returned from the source, it doesn't even get to the split condition.

How can I make a split on a 0 row return??

Comment: Could you help me understand what you want to do when there are zero rows in your source system. Feel free to patch in a screen shot of the control flow and or data flow to help me visualize the desired state

Comment: Nothing crazy. I'm working with sharepoint and I am pulling from a list (source) in sharepoint. I have a query that is checking the column name for a specific entry. If the entry is there update the information for that entry and if that entry is not there then add it to the sharepoint list. When the entry is not there the result returns 0 rows, this is what I want, but how to split [Also note, I am using KingsWaySoft for the sharepoint source)

Comment: Perform the test in the control flow. Execute SQL. Select COUNT(*) from whatever into a variable and then put a constraint on that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Data Flow, when no rows are read from a source, the Data Flow stops.
One approach would be to get your source return the row count and not the rows itself.
Then you could make an conditional split on that number.
In the part where the count is higher than 0 you can get your rows from your source.